# Pygame/MoviePy - The video displays with a terrible framerate and the window size is bigger than my screen

Tags: python, video, pygame, moviepy

I've been looking around for a while trying to find a way to display videos in Pygame because of a new story video-game project. I finally stumbled across Moviepy which works alright...except that the video displays showing only one of the 24 frames each second and the window it displays in is bigger than by screen.
(on a Windows 10 laptop with an 11inch(I think) screen)

The sound is alright but the video also goes too fast so is out of sync.

I've tried the resize function as said on the docs but it gives no effect.

And I can't find anything to do with the framerate.

So I need a way to make the window smaller and correct the framerate.

This is the code I used:

```py
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from moviepy.video.fx.resize import resize
import pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('My video!')

clip = VideoFileClip('Eleeza Crafter And The Cloud Colours Trailer.mp4')
clip.fx(resize, width=240)
clip.preview(fps=24)
pygame.quit()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

EDIT: I tested a different video at the same framerate and it works perfectly?
Then again it was just a simple line flying around the screen.

Comment: What did you tried for the resize ? It does not appear in your question.

Comment: @LoneWanderer `clip.resize(width=1000)`  just before the preview The docs say the height would resize itself according to the ratio

Comment: Obviously the width you set may feel too big depending on your rendering device size. Did you try several values to check if the resize actually does something ? BTW you should edit your post with some actual working/not working code, some expected output vs actual output when possible.

Comment: Hmm, well I also tried to resize by 0.5, to make it half the size...didn't work

Comment: This may also depend on the context you are executing in : iphyton, Jupyter, console, python version, module version...  more info needed !

Comment: I use IDLE to program

Comment: What are your versions of pygame ? of python ? the relevant dependancies installed with their versions (see my updated answer)? Pygame is in version 1.9.6 as of april 2019 (https://www.pygame.org/news/2019/4/pygame-1-9-6-released-with-a-few-regression-bug-fixes). Are you using a RaspberryPi or a specific platform ? What is your screen size ? We *really* need more informations to help you out. Otherwise, you won't have any answer.

Comment: I'm using Pygame 1.9.4, and Python 3.6

Comment: It looks like the functions to resize return a `VideoFileClip` object. Did you try something like `clip = clip.resize(width = 240)`?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon The clip resizes perfectly! Thank you very much :) Perhaps I could use something similar to fix the framerate too?

Comment: I don't think that would work. The code for the `preview` function can be found [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/dbc9ab13c022fdcd7ed529d2ea7fab4b4ef329a5/moviepy/video/io/preview.py) and does not clearly return any clips and instead controls the event loop. Contrast that with the `resize` function which does return a new `VideoFileClip` object (see [here](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/dbc9ab13c022fdcd7ed529d2ea7fab4b4ef329a5/moviepy/video/fx/resize.py)). I have not used `moviepy` so I am not sure how exactly it works.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon Hmm, yes, that does make sense. I already tried to `clip.preview(fps=24)` and use the `set_fps()` method and both gave no effect.

Comment: At my computer now and trying out `moviepy`. It appears that the `preview` function works as intended for me as you have written, although the framerate chokes with high resolution videos. What is the resolution and frame rate of the video you are playing?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon The resolution is 1920x1080p, resized it to  width 1000px. The frame rate is 24fps, but if I understand correctly, MoviePy’s default FPS is 15.

Comment: In that case I am pretty sure it is due to the HD resolution of the video file requiring too much processing to generate the data for each frame in moviepy. Try looking at the Task Manager and see the %cpu being used. I think a quick workaround is to use a tool like HandBrake or ffmpeg to preprocess or convert your video in advance to the desired resolution (i.e make the video file itself have a width of 1000 px).

Comment: From their main page, MoviePy is stated as a Python module for video editing. Since all you want is to play a clip, have you considered other modules, like [VLC for python](http://example.com)? It is quite easy to use as well.

Comment: That’s an example.com link. But I’ll google it.

Answer (score 1):

A 2 seconds google gave me [this link](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/efficient_moviepy.html).

It states :

> A clip can be previewed as follows

```
my_clip.preview() # preview with default fps=15
my_clip.preview(fps=25)
my_clip.preview(fps=15, audio=False) # don't generate/play the audio.
my_audio_clip.preview(fps=22000)
```

Also (depending of your import method:

> This way you can use `clip.resize(width=240)` instead of the longer `clip.fx( resize, width=240)`.

Still from the documentation:

> For advanced image processing you will need one or several of these packages. For instance using the method clip.resize requires that at least one of **Scipy**, **PIL**, **Pillow** or **OpenCV** are installed.

Comment: Still nothing. :( sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the problem, but for screen size you should use `pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))` (change the `WIDTH` value to your desired width and the `HEIGHT` value to your desired height. Also, something I have noticed with pygame is that the big windows have lots of lag, so maybe a smaller window size would be recommended. I find that 500x500 is the maximum size for no lag (at least on my laptop)

Comment: It resized itself to the oversized video so...nope, sorry.

Comment: Huh. Okay... Then I don't think I can answer the question. I've never worked with moviepy, only Pygame.